# css3 and a way to color a span as a circle with a different half as background

Tags: css, less

so, I have some html layout and I cannot change the html, ONLY the css. Now, I can achieve the colors I want and create that circle (see image), with border-radius. Here is the rub, each square is a span. There are no inner divs/outer divs.. just the span. Is there a way to achieve, with css, that circle and then the half background fill.

the code would be, on a base level:

```
<span class="day is-range is-selected" />22</span>
<span class="day is-range" />23</span>
```

Basically, when a user selects a date, I color it that bright reddish color, make it a circle, make the other dates backgrounds that more bourbon red color.. great... BUT the selected date with the cirle doesn't have that "bleed into" the other square look with half its span colored. Is there a way to achieve this with css and no mods to the html?

I've only been able to achieve the following:

[image: What I have]

What I want to achieve.

[image: What I want to achieve]

This is really what I am trying to achieve. The span, goes to a circle, I can do that - but somehow make half of the span have a different background color.

[image]

The CSS I am using is fairly trivial. Note, I have to use !important to override what is gen'ed.

```
  .is-selected {
    background-color: @selected-background !important;
    color: @base;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }



  .is-inRange {
    background-color: @active-background !important;
    color: @base;
  }
```

Comment: Instead of images please could you include the CSS code you used to get that result. This should be possible, pseudo elements would be one method.

Comment: I am not sure why two images, showing what I have and what I want is not clear enough. Basically, it is a black background with a number, when I click it - it goes to a circle and I want it have a half background.. let me add another image to show it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pseudo-element would seem the only option here as the HTML cannot be altered.

The specificity has be managed though:

```css
 .day {
   float: left;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   background: plum;
   line-height: 40px;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
 }
 .is-range {
   background: plum;
 }
 .is-range.is-selected {
   background-color: red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: relative;
 }
 .is-range.is-selected:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 50%;
   height: 100%;
   left: 50%;
   background: plum;
   z-index: -1;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="day is-range is-selected">22</span>
  <span class="day is-range">23</span>
  <span class="day is-range">24</span>
  <span class="day is-range">25</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like answers are using the same solution.

Comment: Ok. Just mentioned it.

Comment: thank you very much.... I believe these will work great. Since they both work, i upvoted both and just accepted whomever posted the answer first.

Comment: That would be Qwertiy, by about 7 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.day {
  float: left;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background: silver;
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.is-selected {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.is-selected:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: silver;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<span class="day is-range is-selected">22</span>
<span class="day is-range">23</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

If both days are in one row:

```css
.day {
  float: left;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background: silver;
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.is-selected {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.is-selected + .day {
  margin-left: -1.5em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<span class="day is-range is-selected">22</span>
<span class="day is-range">23</span>
```